# Is it bad practice to use a domain controller as private web server?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, internal-dns

Assuming correct security settings is in place, is it bad practice to use a domain controller and DNS server as web server? 
I don't mean a public website but rather a ERP. 
The server will have other software on that are related to network management such as unifi controller for our wifi. But I would like to have our custom ERP on there too which will be accessible outside the network on private URL. 
The domain controller has about 30 computers under it. Oh and this is MS active directory of course.

Thanks in advance. ☺️

Comment: `Assuming correct security settings is in place, is it bad practice to use a domain controller and DNS server as web server?` - Yes it is.

Comment: @joeqwerty is that just because it's accessible from the outside? Or just generally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is bad practice. One example why is because if one of the secondary functions interferes (crashes the box, hogs the memory, fills a disk, etc) with the primary function (serving authentication requests), this could have wide spread impacts in the domain.